# C# Publish Issue - Unknown .pfx Password

Tags: c#, passwords, pfx

I had a developer that created a beta application in C# for one of our clients.  The developer has left quite suddenly and when I attempted to make changes to the app then publish it, it asked me for a password for the .pfx which I don't have.

In Visual Studio, I went into the project properties, then to Signing and under the Choose a Strong Name Key file, I selected a  and created a new file with password.  Even with this change, the system is still looking for the old .pfx file and password.

I've Googled and Googled.  Is there a way to generate a new file and password without having to re-engineer this entire thing?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this by doing the following:

1. Open the project folder in Windows Explorer.
2. Find the .pfx file.
3. Delete the .pfx file.
4. Open the solution in Visual Studio.
5. Go to Properties
6. Go to Signing
7. Select Sign the Assembly
8. Create a new key file name and generate a password
9. At the top of the Signing page, click Select from File
10. Browse to the new .pfx file
11. Enter the password
12. Publish the app

It means a re-install of the application for the users but since I am doing a code upgrade anyway, I was going to have to do that.